# Objective-C: json response from jquery callback

Tags: php, jquery, ios, objective-c, ajax

I'm building and iOS application and 
trying to get the json data from a url similar to:

example.com/ajax/u.php?callback=jQuery84054761566_1389381628746

Is anyone familiar with these types of callbacks?

Typical HTTP requests in obj-c return 200 status and a null response object with this url.

Comment: Many of us are familiar with network-based operations retrieving JSON. Could you elaborate on what the problem you're having is and what you've tried? Please post your `NSURLRequest` or `NSURLSession` code.

Comment: Apparently, that's a JSONP url. You may want to remove the starting **jQuery84054761566_1389381628746(** and the ending **)** and then do the JSON parsing

Comment: I'd start with making sure you're hitting the right URL and getting the response you expect. Use [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/) before you code it for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a JSONP callback used for...well, JSONP. JSONP is used on webpages to avoid the 'same origin' restriction. That is, a webpage loaded from a certain domain (say abc.com) cannot call/access resources on a separate domain (say xyz.com).

The way they (web front-end developers) get around this is by using the `<script>` tag which is exempt from this restriction. However the return of a `<script>` tag would just be parsed - to cause it to execute something, you tell it a function name that exists in your JavaScript code, in this case, `jQuery84054761566_1389381628746`.

So instead of returning a regular JavaScript object, say

```
{key : 'value'}
```

the server then returns a function invocation

```
jQuery84054761566_1389381628746({key : 'value'})
```

and you have, in your webpage JavaScript, the function definition for `jQuery84054761566_1389381628746` that does something:

```
jQuery84054761566_1389381628746 = function(data){
  alert(data.key);
};
```

iOS does not have this same-origin/cross-site restriction so you don't need JSONP - you can call whatever server you want.